# Generate and save hash based on uploaded file

Tags: python, django

Currently I am able to upload files in Django Admin using a `FileField`. What I want to achieve is:

- Creating a hash based on the uploaded file and save it as a field
- Determine the `file_size` of the uploaded file and save it as a field

My `models.py`

```
class File(models.Model):
    file_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    file_mime = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    file_size = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    file_hash = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    data = models.FileField(upload_to=get_dynamic_path)  
    customer_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I tried to override the `save()` method like this:

```
# models.py

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    f = self.data.open('rb')
    h = hashlib.sha1()
    if f.multiple_chunks():
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            h.update(chunk)
    else:
        h.update(f.read())
    f.close()
    self.sha1 = h.hexdigest()
    self.file_size = self.data.size
    super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I upload a file, it uploads just fine but the `file_size` and `file_hash` fields are empty.

What do I need to change in order to:

- Succesfully generate a hash based on the uploaded file and save it in the `file_hash` field.
- Determine the file size of the uploaded file and save it in the `file_size` field.

**EDIT**:
Fixed formatting mistake on StackOverflow so it resembles my actual code.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to call super twice, this will cause the model to save twice. Just call it at the end. Also is this formatted correctly? The else doesn't line up with the if and everything from the f.close() should be outside of the if/else?

Comment: also your indentation looks strange, `for` loops can have [`else` clauses](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html)

Comment: I made a mistake formatting the last bit on here. Thanks for pointing it out. Changed it so it resembles my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things to note:
1. You don't need to call `super` twice as pointed out by mikeyj.
2. If you are overriding save, check whether you have to calculate the hash or not.

```
# models.py

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.file_size is None:
        f = self.data.open('rb')
        h = hashlib.sha1()
        if f.multiple_chunks():
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                h.update(chunk)
        else:  # changed indentation as per my understanding of your code
            h.update(f.read())
        self.sha1 = h.hexdigest()
        self.file_size = self.data.size
        f.close()  # make sure to close the file after operation is done
    super(File, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```